# Anaconda Navigatorが起動しない

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, spyder

pythonw.exeを実行し、Anaconda Navigatorを起動させようとしましたが、
砂時計のマークがしばらく表示されてからすぐ消えるだけで、何も起動しません。

Anaconda Promptや[jupyter-notebook](/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook)は起動しますが、[spyder](/questions/tagged/spyder)も同様に起動できない状況です。

どうすればAnaconda Navigatorが起動できるか、解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

一応Anaconda Promptで

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

を入力して、Anaconda Navigatorが最新バージョン(1.9.2, 2018年11月26日現在)であることは確認済みですが、

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

を入力しても無反応で、Anaconda Navigatorをリセット出来ませんでした。

ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

### 追記

OSはWindows10を使っております。

`C:\Programs\Anaconda3` には `bin` というディレクトリが見つからないのですが、代わりに `C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Scripts` というディレクトリに anaconda-navigator.exe と spyder.exe がございました。
ユーザー環境変数の Path も `C:\Programs\Anaconda3 C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Scripts` が設定されております。

コマンドプロンプトで anaconda-navigator を入力したり、エクスプローラーから anaconda-navigator.exe を実行しても、起動がうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: Anaconda Navigator, spyderは、anaconda/binディレクトリにインストールされるので、anaconda/binディレクトリにパスが通っていれば、ターミナルからだとAnaconda-Navigatorとコマンドを打つだけで起動するはずです。 起動しないのは環境の問題なので、使っているOSがWindowsかMacか、PATHをどう設定しているか教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows版のAnacondaをインストールする時にPATHを追加する設定にすると、C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3, C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts 以外に以下のディレクトリーがPATHに設定されます。（ディレクトリ名は全ユーザーの場合の既定のフォルダー名にしています。それ以外の場合は適宜読み替えてください）

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

調べてみると、Anaconda Navigator, Spyder を直接コマンドプロンプトやエクスプローラーから起動する場合、上記のディレクトリーがPATHがなければ起動しません。

したがって、コマンドプロンプトから Anaconda Navigator, Spyder を起動したい場合は、上記のフォルダーをPATHに追加するか、`Conda activate`で先にAnacondaの環境を起動するか、`Anaconda Prompt`を起動してそこから実行するか、してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Libraryフォルダの下にusrというフォルダがなかったので、

    C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
    C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Library\bin

の2つだけをPATHに加えてみましたが、コマンドプロンプトとエクスプローラーの両方共で、Anaconda Navigator, Spyderを起動することが出来ませんでした。また、Anaconda Promptでも起動することができませんでした。

usrフォルダがないことが問題でしょうか。

Comment: 新規インストールの状態ではusrフォルダーはないので、それが問題ではないと思います。どの方法でも起動できないとなるとライブラリーに不整合が生じていると思われるので、現在のAnacondaをアンインストールして、新規にインストールした方が簡単だと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。仰る通り、再インストールしたところ、Anaconda Navigator, Spyder両方とも無事起動することができました。何度もご丁寧に教えていただき、大変助かりました。